# WooCommerce conditional inventory change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get this bit of PHP to work on a build. The goal is to have Item Y update its stock status to "out of stock" if Item X becomes out of stock. Here is what I have:

```
/* Conditional inventory tracking. If Item X is out of stock, make Item Y out of stock also */

function update_related_product_stock( $product_id ) {
    // Check if the product is Item X or Item Y
    if ( $product_id == 123 || $product_id == 456 ) { // Replace 123 and 456 with the actual product IDs of Item X and Item Y
        $item_1_stock = get_post_meta( 123, '_stock', true ); // Replace 123 with the actual product ID of Item X

        // Update stock of Item Y based on stock of Item X
        if ( $item_1_stock <= 0 ) {
            update_post_meta( 456, '_stock_status', 'outofstock' ); // Replace 456 with the actual product ID of Item Y
        } else {
            update_post_meta( 456, '_stock_status', 'instock' ); // Replace 456 with the actual product ID of Item Y
        }
    }
}
// Hook the function to run when stock levels are updated
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'update_related_product_stock' );
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction with this? Thanks in advance!

Item X runs out of stock, Item Y should automatically set to "Out of Stock". Replaced the above with WooCommerce Product IDs on a pair of test items. I set Item X out of stock, but then Item Y remained in stock. I tried both with and without stock quantity management active for Item Y, and saw the same result both with and without it active.